# How to get data from an phrase in remote XML in php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I wanna get the data from an XML file on remote site from a particular node. But im getting the following error

**Warning: simplexml_load_file():** in php line

on the warning 2 : Its loading the File data. Result I wanna is to get the ***GRate***.

Note: I have enabled SimpleXML module on my php installation.

```
<?php
  $url = "http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("not open");

  ?><pre><?php //print_r($xml); ?></pre><?php

  foreach($xml->GRate as $GRate){
    printf('$GRate');
  }
?>
```

I have expected to get "3640.00" on my output but error is as follows

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in H:\root\home\srinivasauser-001\www\goldrate\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\footer.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): {"GRate":"3640.00","SRate":"49.00","PRate":"0.00"} in H:\root\home\srinivasauser-001\www\goldrate\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\footer.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in H:\root\home\srinivasauser-001\www\goldrate\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\footer.php on line 24
not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the URL "`http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate`" is requested from PHP with the default settings, it will return the data as JSON. Which *might* be even easier to parse in this case:

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '$GRate: ' . $json->GRate, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$GRate: 3670.00
```

This can be easily checked by fetching the URL and output it verbatim:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
echo $buffer, "\n";
```

```
{"GRate":"3670.00","SRate":"50.00","PRate":"0.00"}
```

As has been [demonstrated by *Vijay Dohare*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58395172/367456) it is possible to tell that server that XML is preferred. To check if that works, is possible this way, too:

```
stream_context_get_default(['http' => ['header' => 'Accept: application/xml']]);
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
echo $buffer, "\n";
```

The output is not that beautified then (I guess if the data is more, the JSON wouldn't be that easy to read as well as it also would grew larger):

```
<GetRateController.Rate xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Savings.Controllers"><GRate>3670.00</GRate><PRate>0.00</PRate><SRate>50.00</SRate></GetRateController.Rate>
```

This might be similar to when opening the URL in the browser. This is because the browser also sends the `Accept` request header and it contains XML as well:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
```

Because browser normally accept XML as well (albeit they prefer HTML over it).

So in the end it depends what *you* prefer. Either the [JSON which is less verbose compared to XML](http://json.org/) (see the very first example code above) or if you want to use XML with SimpleXML:

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate";
stream_context_get_default(['http' => ['header' => 'Accept: application/xml']]);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("not open");

echo '$GRate: ' . $xml->GRate, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$GRate: 3670.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
<?php
  $url = "http://api.srinivasajewellery.com/getrate/getrate";
  $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));

  $xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml) or die("not open");

  foreach($xml->GRate as $GRate){
    echo '$GRate: '.$GRate;
  }
?>
```